# Where do I find Stanford NLP Tagger training files for: english-left3words-distsim.tagger

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to understand how to train my own tagger in Stanford NLP. How do I get the training files for:

english-left3words-distsim.tagger

It lists these files in the props file, but not too sure on the full download url.

/u/nlp/software/CoreNLP-models/models/english-left3words-distsim-4.1.1-v5/data/wsj-train.tagged.txt;
/u/nlp/software/CoreNLP-models/models/english-left3words-distsim-4.1.1-v5/data/ewt-train.tagged.txt;
/u/nlp/software/CoreNLP-models/models/english-left3words-distsim-4.1.1-v5/data/ontonotes-train.tagged.txt;
/u/nlp/software/CoreNLP-models/models/english-left3words-distsim-4.1.1-v5/data/craft-train.tagged.txt;
/u/nlp/software/CoreNLP-models/models/english-left3words-distsim-4.1.1-v5/data/english-handparsed-train.tagged.txt;
/u/nlp/software/CoreNLP-models/models/english-left3words-distsim-4.1.1-v5/data/questionbank-train.tagged.txt

Any suggestions?

Comment: use "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-caseless-left3words-distsim.tagger" according to stanford-corenlp-4.4.0

Comment: Thx, what is the full url?